# will php's mail() attempt to deliver to localhost?

Tags: php, email, localhost

We are having a problem with a web application delivering emails. Suppose the site lives on `domain.com`. Emails sent to `manager@domain.com` aren't being recieved by the client, but when we set it to `developer@developersdomain.com` or `manager@aliasdomain.com` they are received by the developer and the manager, respectively.

Is php's mail() command delivering email addresses to the location domain to localhost, instead of routing it through a mail server?

Comment: Are you sending to the full address and not user@localhost if it is on your domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is the way that the mailserver itself works.  It knows the machine it's on is `domain.com` and assumes the mailbox should be a local box.

This is why it's a good idea to have your server's domain name actually be a subdomain, even if it's just `www.domain.com`.  That way, mail addressed to `manager@domain.com` is sent on to the mail server specified by `domain.com`'s MX record.

Answer (score 1):

That'll be a setting on your mail software at the serverside I guess! Check your software settings.